# Get dates in range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a start date and an end date. I want to use datepart to check if any of the dates in between fall on weekends. How do I get the dates in between? Since they are not in a field I can't select them.

Comment: Do you actually need to get the dates in between, or is enough to know that it spans a weekend?

Answer (score 0):

For this a calendar table would come in handy, but unless you have one already you can generate a series of the dates in between your start and end dates using a number sequence and test the weekday of each date in the series like below.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 --set the start of the week to Monday.
DECLARE @startdate date = '2014-10-01', @enddate date = '2014-10-31'
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,@startdate)
FROM master..spt_values 
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number,@startdate) <= @enddate
AND DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(DAY,number,@startdate)) IN (6,7)
```

This code will list all Saturdays and Sundays in October and the result will be:

```
2014-10-04
2014-10-05
2014-10-11
2014-10-12
2014-10-18
2014-10-19
2014-10-25
2014-10-26
```

Comment: Thanks jpw. Can you explain what the where type = 'P' does? I will need to do this for stat holidays as well, so yes user2321368 I will need the actual dates... but I figured one step at a time.

Comment: @brndnmlk The system table`master..spt_values`contain different types of data, and the`type='p'`happens to be a sequence of integers (0-2047) that can be used to generate a sequence of dates (and other things as well).